# Google play console deobfuscate crashes

Tags: android, crash-reports, google-play-console

I have some hard time deobfuscating the google play console crashes. The app contains a library that uses proguard. I want to be able to deobfucate the crashes that happen in the library. I uploaded the `mapping.txt` file but the crash logs still looks weird. Some example of how it looks like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.my.lib.MyWriter.writeTo (MyWriter.java)
  at <OR>.readFrom (MyWriter.java)
  at <OR>.readStringFrom (MyWriter.java)
  at <OR>.writeStringTo (MyWriter.java)
  at <OR>.getSize (MyWriter.java)
  at <OR>.sizeOf (MyWriter.java)
  at com.my.lib.ModelObject.getProperty (ModelObject.java)
  at <OR>.setProperty (ModelObject.java)
  at <OR>.setProperty (ModelObject.java)
  at <OR>.setProperty (ModelObject.java)
  at <OR>.writeTo (ModelObject.java)
  at <OR>.readFrom (ModelObject.java)
  at <OR>.getSize (ModelObject.java)
```

What does those `<OR>` mean? The crash log pretty much lists some of the objects from the library with their methods. How should I read this?